# polymer render layout after dynamic injection

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a polymer template where part of it is a jquery component injected at runtime using attched method.

```
<template>
        <div class="layout vertical">
            <div id="host" style="width: 95%; height: 75%;position:absolute; margin: 10px 10px;"></div>
            <paper-toggle-button class="layout horizontal end-justified" style="margin-right: 10px">Toggle</paper-toggle-button>
        </div>
</template>
```

Even though I have set my `flex layout` to be `vertical` the toggle shows at the top. I see why as the content is not available when the component is rendered. But can I call any `Polymer.dom` methods after attaching the jquery component so that the toggle repositions itself below the host component ? `Polymer.dom.flush()` din't work.

Comment: Injecting DOM into an instance of `#host` should just work and have nothing to do with Polymer. Mixing `position: absolute` and `layout vertical` (flex-box) is a strange combination, are you sure your CSS is correct?

Comment: even if i remove div styles it still stays at the top. I just wonder if toggle button gets into the dom before the host content takes the space in attached method ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to call `Polymer.updateStyles();` to inform Polymer that you have changed the styling and need it to redo any internal stuff.